# NDK r16b std::istringstream doesn't behave as expected

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have an app which its native code was compiled using NDK r12b.
But now I want to migrate to NDK r16b.

I use the standalone toolchain to compile my app (both for r12b and r16b).
the arguments that I used to make the toolchain is:

```
make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --api 15 --stl libc++
```

after using r16b, i found that std::istringstream doesn't split whitespace-separated numbers like " 0.4 0.5 ". the output of istringstream is still " 0.4 0.6 " instead of 0.4 and 0.6.

also, if there's a minus sign (-) it will split the input, for example:
"armeabi-v7a" will become "armeabi" and "v7a".
while when i use r12b the istringstream won't split and will output "armeabi-v7a".
I used this snippet to check:

```
const char* input = " 0.4 0.5 "
std::istringstream iss(input);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "myTag","istringstream input = %s", input);
for (std::istream_iterator<std::string> it = std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss); it != std::istream_iterator<std::string>(); it++)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "myTag", "istringstream content = %s", it->c_str() ? it->c_str() : "NULL");
}
```

I used clang as the compiler and these are the command line that i used:

compile options:

```
-fsigned-char
-fno-exceptions
-fno-rtti
-pipe
-ferror-limit=1000
-stdlib=libc++
-std=c++11
-D__ANDROID_API__=15
-mfpu=vfpv3-d16
-mfloat-abi=softfp
-target armv7a-none-linux-androideabi
-marm
-march=armv7-a
-mtune=generic-armv7-a
--sysroot $NDK_Root$/sysroot
-g
-O0
```

Link options:

```
-lOpenSLES
-lGLESv2
-lEGL
-latomic
-landroid
-llog
-lm
-lz
-ldl
-lc++_shared
-lgcc
-lc
-Wl,--build-id
-target armv7a-none-linux-androideabi
-no-canonical-prefixes
-march=armv7-a
-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8
-Wl,-z,noexecstack
-Wl,--no-undefined
-Wl,-z,relro
-Wl,-z,now
-nostdlib
--sysroot $NDK_Root$/sysroot
```

Anyone can give me insight on why is this happens? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was copying libc++_shared.so from NDK r12b to my APK and that's is the cause of that weird behaviour.

That was stupid, i conclude the case closed.